# identify incoming caller android and display in toast

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a simple phonebook application where I can perform a search and an API will return the information. So far this is the part that I've got working.

I also want incoming caller to be identified with the same API, that would require the incoming number from Broastcastreceiver to be put into the API query and the returned information should be displayed in a toast. This is the part I'm having problems with.

So far this is what I have. Apologize if its really messy, this is what I've been playing around with recently and made small adjustments. Also its alot of copy-paste, I'm a beginner at java/Android and trying to learn.

**HttpHandler.java**

```
package se.xx.api_test;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpHandler extends PhoneCallReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    public HttpHandler() {
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**PhoneCallReceiver.java**

```
package se.xx.api_test;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    public static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package se.xx.api_test;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tv;
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView lv;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textInput);

        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }

                contactList.clear();
                new GetContacts().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Json Data is downloading",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            String id = tv.getText().toString();
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/api/api.php?id="+id;
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String namn = c.getString("namn");
                        String avdelning = c.getString("avdelning");
                        //String telnr = c.getString("telnr");

                        //JSONObject data = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                        //String namn = data.getString("namn");
                        //String avdelning = data.getString("avdelning");
                        //String telnr = data.getString("telnr");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobil = phone.getString("mobil");
                        String telnr = phone.getString("telnr");
                        //String office = phone.getString("office");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        //HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("namn", namn);
                        contact.put("avdelning", avdelning);
                        contact.put("mobil", mobil);
                        contact.put("telnr", telnr);
                        //contact.put("phone", phone);
                        //contact.put("namn", namn);
                        //contact.put("avdelning", avdelning);
                        //contact.put("telnr", telnr);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "namn","avdelning","mobil", "telnr"},
                    new int[]{R.id.email, R.id.mobile, R.id.mobil, R.id.telnr});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

**CallReceiver.java** (this is what I've been playing around with)

```
package se.xx.api_test;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import java.lang.String;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;


public class CallReceiver extends PhoneCallReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {

        final String phnr = String.valueOf(R.id.mobile);

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) toast.getView();
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) group.getChildAt(0);
        messageTextView.setTextSize(25);
        toast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    private class APICall extends MainActivity {
        String number = getIntent().getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2/api/api.php?id="+number;
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        final String namn = c.getString("namn");
                        String avdelning = c.getString("avdelning");
                        //String telnr = c.getString("telnr");

                        //JSONObject data = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                        //String namn = data.getString("namn");
                        //String avdelning = data.getString("avdelning");
                        //String telnr = data.getString("telnr");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                        String mobil = phone.getString("mobil");
                        String telnr = phone.getString("telnr");
                        //String office = phone.getString("office");

                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        //HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("namn", namn);
                        contact.put("avdelning", avdelning);
                        contact.put("mobil", mobil);
                        contact.put("telnr", telnr);
                        //contact.put("phone", phone);
                        //contact.put("namn", namn);
                        //contact.put("avdelning", avdelning);
                        //contact.put("telnr", telnr);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

which part you got an error ? 
with your Api ? or while receive you phone number from service ?
put your error to clarify the situation

Comment: What I want to do is that I want to take the number that I receive from the CallReceiver java class when it identifies an incoming call and make an API query with it. The returned result (JSON) I want to parse and enter into a toast message that popups on the screen everytime I receive an incoming call.

Comment: so where is your problem what is the mistake or crash you have got ?